# how to add array values to column using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below vba code, I have multiple columns for sample I have provided few.
All I am trying is, if I try to make the changes the same value should restore to the deleted column headers.
Below code is working fine if I make any changes to the range "A1" however if I make any changes other than "A1", code is taking too much of time complete and it is looping too many times.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim headers() As Variant
If Range("A1").Value <> "FIRST" Or Range("B1").Value <> "Second" Or Range("C1").Value <> "Third"  Then
headers() = Array("FIRST", "Second", "Third")
With Sheets("Sheet1")
For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
.Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
 Next i
 .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
End With
End If
```

==============================
Please help me to resolve this issue, appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take care of disabling events before you change the values.
Try the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Header As Variant
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A1:C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Header = Array("FIRST", "Second", "Third")
    Target.Parent.Range("A1:C1").Value = Header
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the value change on `.Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)` triggers the event itself. You're basically going into an endless execution chain like this.

You should either Disable the events during execution of this macro, or do a check on each header.

The simplest solution:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim headers() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False 'This fixes your issue.

If Range("A1").Value <> "FIRST" Or Range("B1").Value <> "Second" Or Range("C1").Value <> "Third" Then
    headers() = Array("FIRST", "Second", "Third")
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
            .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
        Next i
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its working as expected. 

1) However, I have a question, that what is the use of "Option Explicit"? because, code is working fine even without "Option Explicit" piece of code.

2) I need to add a LOV with two values using VBA ("One" and "Two") in Column "A" (A2 to A100). However this should override if I copy paste some other value say "Three", but still LOV should be available for selecting the original value ("One" and "Two").

Please advice me, thanks again in advance for your help.